# passing of form values through <paginate> grails

Tags: grails, pagination

I am implementing pagination through `<g:paginate>` tag in grails.
Can i pass the values in a form through the params in `<g:paginate>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `<g:paginate>` tag supports a `params` attributes that allows you to pass request parameters, e.g.

```
<g:paginate next="Forward" prev="Back"
        maxsteps="0" controller="book"
        action="list" total="${bookCount}" 
        params="[foo: bar, foo2: bar2]/>
```

Comment: can i add a javascript funtion which generates the map and passes it to params??

Comment: Not really....`<g:paginate>` is processed on the server side to generate `<a href="...">click me</a>`, so the link is generated before any JavaScript is run (on the client-side). You could modify the link - which includes the param values - using JavaScript, but it's likely to be a pretty ugly solution